# Fix resolv.conf and get comcast out of my name server list?

Tags: networking, dns

I am confused on how to fix this or even how it came to be. 90% of the time I connect to the internet through my home router and comcast is not listed in the config at all for it. It has its own DNS and things worked great until updating to Ubuntu 18 now none of my local machines resolve (all not found) when I do an nslookup.

```
nslookup data1
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find data1: SERVFAIL

nslookup data1 192.168.1.1
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Name:   data1
Address: 192.168.1.113
```

Here is the results of ifconfig showing my last interface is my wifi and is connected to the correct network:

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 28:f1:0e:4a:a4:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 220635  bytes 104082409 (104.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 220635  bytes 104082409 (104.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::686f:cec4:768c:d810  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b0:c0:90:50:8e:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9169680  bytes 6584220987 (6.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10685113  bytes 13298441288 (13.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is the contents of my resolv.conf file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search wp.comcast.net
```

Here is the output from systemd-resolve --status showing a ton of junk in the GLOBAL section and showing the DNS on the router at 192.168.1.1 but that appears to be ignored based on the lookups shown above.

```
Global
          DNS Domain: wp.comcast.net
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (wlp3s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

Link 2 (enp2s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

Anyone know how to get my nslookups to start using the DNS specified here? And how the heck did that comcast stuff get in there and how do I get it out?

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience with this, but I'm by no means an expert...

You may have a couple of problems...

1. your router may not be setup to use the DNS servers that you desire
2. there may be problems with dnsmasq and systemd-resolved on your 18.04 computer
3. you may need to edit the /etc/hosts file
4. you manually edited /etc/resolv.conf (don't do that)

**1. tweak your router's settings...**

Log into your router's admin page, and check the DNS Server settings. Set them to your desired DNS servers, and save the settings.

**2. tweak your dnsmasq and systemd-resolvd settings...**

dnsmasq and systemd-resolved tend to step on each others toes. Although you can run both, it may cause problems. dnsmasq is left over from previous system, and will remain after a 18.04 upgrade.

**In terminal...**

```
ps auxc | grep -i dnsmasq # to see if dnsmasq is running

ps auxc | grep -i resolv # this should be running in 18.04
```

After fixing your router's settings, uninstall dnsmasq, reboot, and see if your problem is fixed. If you find that you need dnsmasq, reinstall it, and you'll probably need to tweak your systemd-resolved settings.

```
cd /etc/systemd

sudo pico resolved.conf
```

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

reboot and see if your problem is fixed.

**3. Edit /etc/hosts to include your .local names**

Here's a portion of my /etc/hosts file. You'll obviously need to change the system and node names for your configuration. This is an example only.

```
127.0.0.1   Satellite-E55.local Satellite-E55   localhost
127.0.1.1   Satellite-E55
#
# static IP's (systemic network hardware)
#
192.168.0.1 caspurr.local       caspurr         # Netgear router
192.168.0.2 wdacbridge#1.local  wdacbridge#1    # WD AC bridge #1
192.168.0.3 ex6100.local        ex6100          # Netgear EX6100
192.168.0.4 repeater.local      repeater        # Netgear WN2500RP
192.168.0.5 av-bridge.local     av-bridge       # Cisco E2000
#
#192.168.0.6    meow-nas.local      meow-nas    # NAS
#192.168.0.7    zonet-nas.local     zonet-nas   # NAS
#192.168.0.8    woof-nas.local      woof-nas    # NAS
#
# static DHCP's
#
192.168.0.100   ubuntu-eth0.local   ubuntu-eth0 # Toshiba laptop
192.168.0.101   obitalk2.local      obitalk2    # Obitalk VOIP
192.168.0.102   vonage.local        vonage      # Vonage VOIP
192.168.0.103   laserjet.local      laserjet    # HP P1102W printer
#
192.168.0.201   hdhomerun.local     hdhomerun   # Silicon Dust DUAL
192.168.0.202   hdhomerun2.local    hdhomerun2  # Silicon Dust PRIME
192.168.0.203   hdhomerun3.local    hdhomerun3  # Silicon Dust CONNECT
#
# DHCP
#
192.168.0.253   slingbox.local      slingbox    # Slingbox
#
# cable modem
#
192.168.100.1   cablemodem.local    cablemodem  # Mediacom cable modem
#
# DNS
#
208.67.222.222  resolver1.opendns.com   dns1
208.67.220.220  resolver2.opendns.com   dns2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your WiFi connection's IP address is assigned by the router via DHCP protocol, it's probable that the router is configured to announce the DNS servers it learns from you ISP (pretty common if the connection uses PPPoE).

IIRC this is done automatically if the `resolvconf` package is installed.

As **why** you don't see the actual DNS servers listed but `127.0.0.53`, it's because Ubuntu uses a DNS proxy resolver by default.

As a quick fix, you can try *uninstalling* `resolvconf` and creating a new
`/etc/resolv.conf` file with the DNS server you prefer.

For example

```
$> cat /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

$>
```

**DISCLAIMER**

I've always uninstalled `resolvconf` on my machines and everything worked ok, but I don't know what (or which packages) on your system will be broken if you uninstall it.